# User verification through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to make PHP script using prepared statements in order to avoid SQL injection. Also I created 3 php files.

1. `db_connect.php` (here are stored all informations for connecting to the database)
2. `functions.php` (creating session, checking for login attempts, and function `login` -where I probably have made a mistake but can't find it)
3. `process_login.php` (a set of the two files above. It also redirects to `login_success`, error page, or prints **Invalid request** if no POST variables are sent to this page).

In additions is `functions.php` where probably is the mistake, because i'm getting **Invalid request** every time I try to insert some value. No matter if the fields are empty or they contain a value from the database user.

```
<?php


function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
    $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id.

    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_start(); // Start the php session
    session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.   
}

function login($postcode, $ref, $mysqli) {
  // Using prepared Statements means that SQL injection is not possible.
 if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ref_no, postcode FROM customers WHERE ref_no = ?           LIMIT 1")) {
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $postcode,$ref); // Bind "$email" to parameter.
  $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
  $stmt->bind_result($dbref,$dbpostcode); // get variables from result.
    // $stmt->fetch();
  $a = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$a = array('ref' => $dbref , 'postcode' => $dbpostcode);
}

  if ($_POST['ref']==$dbref && $_POST['postcode']==$dbpostcode){ // If the user exists
    // We check if the account is locked from too many login attempts
    if(checkbrute($ref, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Account is locked

        return false;
    } else {
    if($dbref == $ref) { // Check if the password in the database matches the password the user submitted.
        // Password is correct!

          $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Get the IP address of the user.
          $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // Get the user-agent string of the user.

          if(preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,7}$/", $_POST["postcode"]) === 0)
'<p class="errText">Please enter valid postcode!</p>';
          else{ $_SESSION['postcode'] = $postcode;}
          if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{4,6}$/", $_POST["ref"]) === 0) '<p      class="errText">Please enter valid reference number ! </p>';
          else{
          $_SESSION['ref'] = $ref;}
                        // Login successful.
          return true;   
    } else {
        // Password is not correct
        // We record this attempt in the database
        $now = time();
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts (ref_no, time) VALUES ('$ref', '$now')");
        return false;
    }
  }
  } else {
    // No user exists.
    return false;
  }
  }
   }

function checkbrute($ref, $mysqli) {
  // Get timestamp of current time
  $now = time();
  // All login attempts are counted from the past 2 hours.
  $valid_attempts = $now - (2 * 60 * 60);

  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT time FROM login_attempts WHERE ref_no = ? AND    time > '$valid_attempts'")) {
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $ref);
  // Execute the prepared query.
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  // If there has been more than 3 failed logins
  if($stmt->num_rows > 3) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
   }
}

?>
```

And this is `process_login.php` where user verification fails.

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';


sec_session_start(); //

if(isset($_POST['postcode'], $_POST['ref'])) {

  if(login($postcode, $ref, $mysqli) == true) {
  // Login success
  echo 'Success: You have been logged in!';
 } else {
  // Login failed
  header('Location: ./login.php?error=1');
  }
} else {
  // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page.
  echo 'Invalid Request';
}

?>
```

Any help would be most welcome. Thanks.

Comment: On `process_login.php` var_dump() your $_POST right below `sec_session_start();` and see if anything is actually posting. `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Are the form input name attributes named correctly?

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick answers. I ve tried var_dump($_POST)just like kylex said and i get:   **array(0) { } Invalid Request**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one $variable to bind. You are trying to bind two:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ref_no, postcode FROM customers WHERE ref_no = ?           LIMIT 1")) {
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $postcode,$ref); // Bind "$email" to parameter.
```

Only one ? and two bind_param......

Should be:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ref_no, postcode FROM customers WHERE ref_no = ?           LIMIT 1")) {
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $ref); // Bind "$email" to parameter.
```

I have not tested this, but here is what i think you need for login function:

```
function login($postcode, $ref, $mysqli)
{
// Using prepared Statements means that SQL injection is not possible.
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ref_no, postcode FROM customers WHERE ref_no = ? LIMIT 1"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$ref); // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($dbref,$dbpostcode); // get variables from result.
    while ($stmt->fetch())
        {
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
            {
            $now = time();
            if ($_POST['ref'] == $dbref && $_POST['postcode'] == $dbpostcode)
                {// If the user exists
                    if(checkbrute($ref, $mysqli) == true)
                        {                               
                            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts (ref_no, time) VALUES ('".$dbref."', '".$now."')");
                            return false;
                        }
                    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Get the IP address of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    if(!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,7}$/", $_POST["postcode"]))
                        {
                            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts (ref_no, time) VALUES ('".$dbref."', '".$now."')");
                            $error = '<p class="errText">Please enter valid postcode!</p>';
                            return $error;
                        }
                    $_SESSION['postcode'] = $postcode;
                    if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{4,6}$/", $_POST["ref"]))
                        {
                            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts (ref_no, time) VALUES ('".$dbref."', '".$now."')");
                            $error = '<p class="errText">Please enter valid reference number ! </p>';
                            return $error;
                        }
                    $_SESSION['ref'] = $ref;
            return true;
            }
        //no rows returned
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts (ref_no, time) VALUES ('".$dbref."', '".$now."')");
        return false;       
        }
    //no statement fetched
    return false;
    }
//no statment prepared
return false;
}
```

I added this back into the code, but I do not understand the use of it. it is not returned or used in this scope:

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Get the IP address of the user.
$user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // Get the user-agent string of the user.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Roy, i have tried this, but still the same :/

Comment: @user1981437 I edited my answer to show a rework of your login function. Anytime you are using `return`, done correctly you can leave out the `else`. I have not tested this, so give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

try it :

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ref_no, postcode FROM customers WHERE ref_no = ?           LIMIT 1")) {
  $stmt->bind_param('%s%s', $postcode,$ref); // Bind "$email" to parameter.
```

Comment: Thanks Mostafa, i have changed my code but still im getting  the same error.